# ANDROID - OnClick() Button Referencing Issue?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I would like to have my button in the OnClick() method start a new activity, however it does not do anything. I think it is because the view that needs to be inflated would be the LinearLayout LoginLayout but I dont know how to reference it. The button works fine if I define it the way it is defined in the comment block.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
 * android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout LoginLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_login, container, false);

    /*
     * Button btnLogin = (Button) LoginLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
     * btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
     * 
     * Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Blankactivity.class);
     * v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
     * 
     * 
     * } });
     */

    return LoginLayout;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_Login) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Blankactivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: you should use activity context instead of `v.getContext()`. use  `getActivity()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29 and also remove `implements OnClickListener` since you are using annonymous inner class

Answer (score 1):

Remove `implements OnClickListener` since you are using annonymous inner class

```
public class LoginActivity extends Fragment {
   ...
 }
```

Also remove the below

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_Login) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Blankactivity.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

You should use activity context instead of v.getContext().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29

Use `getActivity()` to get the activity context.

```
   Button btnLogin = (Button) LoginLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Blankactivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use android:onclick for the click event in your layout?

If so then you don't need to use implements OnClickListener if you are in an activity.

if you use android:onclick="login" then the method public void login(View v) is called.

If you try to use it in a fragment like here mine experience is that the android:onClick does not work.

In that case do what Raghunandan says.

or

```
Button btnLogin = (Button) LoginLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

to use the button if you use implement onClickListener